# Why return type of async must be void, Task or Task<T>

Tags: .net, async-await, c#-5.0

I am trying get my hands dirty with async CTP and I noticed that the compiler complains about the async return type. What is the problem with other types?

A simple demo

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    DoWork();
    Console.WriteLine("Returned to main");
    Console.Read();
}

// why do I need to return void, Task or Task<T> here?
// I know I can use something like Task<IEnumerable<string>>
private static async string[] DoWork()
{
    Console.WriteLine("DoWork started");
    return await Task.Factory.StartNew(
        delegate
        {
            Thread.Sleep(2000);                
            Console.WriteLine("DoWork done");
            return new List<string>();
        });        
}
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

On the `await` [consumption] side, we are flexible: we can await any type so long as it
has the right methods.

On the `async` method [production] side, we are inflexible: we are hard-coded to
return only the Task type (or void).
Why the inconsistency?

1. **Iterators already have this behavior...**

   An iterator method (one which has a “yield” inside) is hard-coded to return either
   IEnumerable or IEnumerator.
   However, you can “foreach” over any type which has
   GetEnumerator/MoveNext/Current members.
   So Async is just following suite.
2. **A task is like a future, so it’s good to hard-code it...**

   A Task is barely more than a future.
   A future is a basic fundamental part of a language/platform.
   There’s no reason for a language two have multiple copies of such a fundamental
   notion. One is enough. It’s so foundational that you might even add keywords to the
   language to deal with futures.
   Anyway, if someone has a future-like thing, or a richer notion of task, then they can
   build it out of Task or Func.
   (Our Tasks are already running. If you want to build something that’s “cold”, like F#
   asyncs or like IObservable, one which doesn’t start until you tell it – then you should
   build it out of a Func rather than out of a Task).
3. **Further subtleties**

   Define this function:

   ```
   void f<T>(Func<Task<T>> f)
   ```

   And invoke it:

   ```
   f( () => 1 + await t )
   ```

   We’d like to be able to infer that T=int in this case. Such inference isn’t possible unless
   the compiler has hard-coded knowledge that the lambda it passes to “f” has type
   `Task<int>`.

Source: [*Technical intro to the Async CTP*](http://blogs.msdn.com/cfs-file.ashx/__key/CommunityServer-Blogs-Components-WeblogFiles/00-00-01-12-06/4466.Technical-intro-to-the-Async-CTP.pdf)

Answer (score 8):

Because a `Task<TResult>` is a "future" - a value that will be coming along later. A `string[]` is something you have right now.

Similarly, `Task` is an operation that will complete (either successfully or with an error) sometime in the future.

`void` is something of a special case; it represents a top-level operation in the Async CTP.

If you're wondering why the `Task` isn't automatically inferred, this was considered but rejected by the Async CTP team. Their rationale is [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/async/thread/0ee0af6a-3034-4ac3-aa82-cb6bd62a9ab9), and [this thread](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/async/thread/6dbc3f00-b302-4e6b-9b97-419bc242c0d8) also covers it.