# How to make this sequence printed asynchronously?

Tags: c#, asynchronous

Below code output is this:

0123456789101112131415161718192021222324252627282930313233343536373839404142434445464748495051525354555657585960616263646566676869707172737475767778798081828384858687888990919293949596979899XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX

I should make the output mixed like this:

01234X5X678XX...

I mean both methods should be started asynchronously instead of one starting after the first one finished completely. Where to modify in below code to achieve this?

```
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApplication36
{
class Program
{
    public static void CountForward()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) { Console.Write(i); }
    }

    public static void PrintX()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) { Console.Write("X"); }
    }

    public async Task RunAsync()
    {
        Task t1 = Task.Run(() => CountForward());
        Task t2 = Task.Run(() => PrintX());
        Task[] tasks = { t1, t2 };
        await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Task t = new Program().RunAsync();
        t.Wait();
    }
}
}
```

Comment: The first task simply completes before the second one is started. Start them at the same time for a greater chance of them interleaving.

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16728338/how-can-i-run-both-of-these-methods-at-the-same-time-in-net-4-5

Comment: how to start them at the same time?

Comment: If you want to do parallel work, use the `Parallel` class. If you want to do asynchronous work, use the `Task` class. Attempting to do parallel work through asynchronous classes is pretty bad.

Comment: don't mix "asynchronous" and "parallel/concurrent"