# Async C# Method not returning a string

Tags: c#, visual-studio, function, asynchronous, methods

I have created a Function that returns a string value, but I get the error saying:

> The return type of an async method must be void, Task or Task

This is the code:

```
private async string SerialRead()
{
    const uint maxReadLength = 1024;
    DataReader dataReader = new DataReader(SerialPort.InputStream);
    uint bytesToRead = await dataReader.LoadAsync(maxReadLength);
    string rxBuffer = dataReader.ReadString(bytesToRead);
    return rxBuffer;
}
```

Comment: The error message is clear, direct and correct.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why return type of async must be void, Task or Task<T>](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7010904/why-return-type-of-async-must-be-void-task-or-taskt)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this instead

```
private async Task<string> SerialRead()
{
    const uint maxReadLength = 1024;
    DataReader dataReader = new DataReader(SerialPort.InputStream);
    uint bytesToRead = await dataReader.LoadAsync(maxReadLength);
    string rxBuffer = dataReader.ReadString(bytesToRead);
    return rxBuffer;
}
```